# Qual è il significato di "virgolettato" in questo testo?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *I migliori anni della nostra vita* di Ernesto Ferrero ho letto:

> Alto, imponente come un corazziere, il gran cranio cilindrico **virgolettato** da radi ciuffi di ricci alle orecchie, bocca carnosa, occhiali dalla pesante montatura nera, Malcolm Skey compare in via Biancamano all’inizio degli anni settanta.

Non sono sicura di aver capito il senso di "virgolettato" in questo brano. È chiaro che se ne fa un uso figurato, ma tutti i significati figurati che ho trovato nei dizionari fanno riferimento a parole. Vuol dire "messo in evidenza"?

Comment: A me sembra un'immagine puramente visiva: i ciuffi si trovano in alto ai due lati della testa, come le virgolette attorno ad una parola.

Comment: @DaG: Anch'io inizialmente avevo avuto quest'idea, però credo che la *cilindricità* del cranio sia messa in risalto dai ciuffi di ricci.

Comment: Capisco, ma non la leggo così: per dire che mette in risalto qualcosa forse direbbe "sottolineato", "evidenziato", "messo in grassetto" (per rimanere alle metafore tipografiche). Le virgolette, se non intese in senso puramente grafico, darebbero l'idea di un sottinteso, un doppio senso, un significato figurato, cose che non saprei come applicare a un cranio.

Comment: @DaG: Avevi ragione 

Comment: Ho trovato un riferimento in certo modo simile nel romanzo *Sostiene Pereira* di Antonio Tabucchi, ma in questo caso si tratta di "virgole" invece di "virgolette": «Marta sembrava trasformata, quei capelli biondi e corti, con la frangetta e le **virgole** sulle orecchie, le davano un'aria sbarazzina e straniera, magari francese.»

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neanch'io sono riuscito a trovare riferimenti al significato esteso, ma in analogia con il [contesto discorsivo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/virgolettare/) dovrebbe poter significare "messo in risalto", "messo in evidenza".

In questo caso però è un'immagine puramente visiva, con i ciuffi di ricci che fanno le veci delle virgolette. Grazie a @Benedetta per questa foto che dissipa ogni dubbio: [image]

Comment: Un articolo (http://www.oblique.it/manifesto_skey.html) in cui si parla di Malcom Skey è aperto da una foto che fa capire ancora meglio cosa intenda Ferrero.

Comment: @Benedetta: Gran ritrovamento!